# Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' when running sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXIbi.png)

```
`sudo apt-get update`Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can't seem to find any working solutions on the web.  Could someone help?

Comment: Please provide some details so we can understand your problem better!
What have you already tried? Did you find [this askubuntu question?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) What happened when you tried the solutions you found?